# PHP file reading

Tags: php

I have a txt file with name source.txt and has the following content.

```
Name = "john"
image = "/path"
email = "mail@mail.com"

and some other data
```

I read and echo all the content. But I want specific data and assign to the variable.
if I need name. Then read the file and select john and assign to the variable

Comment: if each line have only 1 data , u can use `fget()` and `explode()` to split the line as key and values

Comment: some file contains  name = "john" | image="/path"

Comment: If all the fields are separated with |, that would be an ideal use for `explode()`. Or you could use `fgetcsv()` and specify the correct separator character. Once you've split them, you can easily parse into variables and values.

Comment: How to assign to a variable

Comment: Use an assignment statement.

Comment: If your files have multiple possible formats, then you need to either know which ones are which OR have some way of identifying the specific format programatically from the file contents itself

Comment: or the easy is get a Json format file , and with a `json_decode()` u work is done

Comment: Please include all representative data formats in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an mini code example

```
test.txt :

Name = "john"
image = "/path"
email = "mail@mail.com"
```

exemple script

```
<?php
$data_array = array();
$data_array_2 = array();
$fp = @fopen("./test.txt", "r");
if ($fp) {
    while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
        array_push($data_array,explode("=",$line));
        list($key,$val) = explode("=",$line);
        $data_array_2[$key] = $val;
    }
}
fclose($fp);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data_array);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data_array_2);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: This would leave trailing spaces in keys, leading spaces in values, and possible linebreaks. Trimming would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native function `parse_ini_file` to parse it like .ini file.

**Example.**

File `test.txt`:

```
Name = "john"
image = "/path"
email = "mail@mail.com"
```

Code (like .ini):

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("test.txt");
print_r($ini_array);

// Result
// Array
// (
//    [Name] => john
//    [image] => /path
//    [email] => mail@mail.com
// )

// Import variables into the current symbol table from an array
// Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. $_GET, $_FILES).
extract($ini_array);
echo $Name; // john
```

**Update.**

File `test2.txt`:

```
name = "john" | image="/path"
name = "john2" | image="/path2"
```

Very simplified code (parse like raw file with lines):

```
function parse_raw_file($filepath) {
    
    $result = [];
    $file = file($filepath);
    
    if(count($file) > 0) {

        foreach($file as $k => $v) {

            $parts = explode("|", $v);
            
            foreach($parts as $part) {

                $value = explode("=", $part);
                $key = trim($value[0]);
                $result[$k][$key] = trim($value[1]);

            }

        }

    }

    return $result; 

}

$array = parse_raw_file("test2.txt");
print_r($array);

// Array
// (
//    [0] => Array
//        (
//            [name] => "john"
//            [image] => "/path"
//        )
//
//    [1] => Array
//        (
//            [name] => "john"
//            [image] => "/path2"
//        )
//
//)

// Assign variables 

foreach ($array as ["name" => $name, "image" => $image]) {
    echo "name: $name, image: $image\n";
}

// name: "john", image: "/path"
// name: "john", image: "/path2"
```

Comment: And if some files are formatted as `Name = "john" | image = "/path" | email = "mail@mail.com"
` like suggested in the question?